# c# object got deleted strangely

Tags: c#, xna

this code get executed after a push of button.

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using xnaWindow.FormUI;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;

namespace xnaWindow.MathClass
{    
    public class Math_Vector 
    {
        private Vector3 vectorA;
        private Vector3 vectorB;
        private Vector3 vectorR;
        private List<float> vResult;

        VertexPositionColor[] verts1,verts2,verts3;

        public void calculate(List<float>v1,List<float>v2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("calculating..");

            vResult = new List<float>(); 
            vectorA = new Vector3(v1.ElementAt(0), v1.ElementAt(1), v1.ElementAt(2));  
            vectorB = new Vector3(v2.ElementAt(0), v2.ElementAt(1), v2.ElementAt(2)); 

            //this is the manual calculation of vector addition
            float xRes = v1.ElementAt(0) + v2.ElementAt(0);
            float yRes = v1.ElementAt(1) + v2.ElementAt(1);
            float zRes = v1.ElementAt(2) + v2.ElementAt(2);

            vectorR = new Vector3(xRes,yRes,zRes);
            //vectorR = vectorA + vectorB; 

            verts1    = new VertexPositionColor[2];
            verts1[0] = new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(0, 0, 0), Color.Black);
            verts1[1] = new VertexPositionColor(vectorA, Color.Black);

            verts2    = new VertexPositionColor[2];
            verts2[0] = new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(0, 0, 0), Color.Black);
            verts2[1] = new VertexPositionColor(vectorB, Color.Black);

            verts3    = new VertexPositionColor[2];
            verts3[0] = new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(0, 0, 0), Color.Black);
            verts3[1] = new VertexPositionColor(vectorR, Color.Black);

            int i = 0;
            //this is for console debug
            foreach (float va in v1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("adding " + va.ToString() + v2.ElementAt(i).ToString());
                vResult.Add(va+v2.ElementAt(i));
                i++;
            }

        }

        public Vector3 getV1(){return vectorA;}
        public Vector3 getV2(){return vectorB;}
        public Vector3 getV3(){return vectorR;}

        public VertexPositionColor[] getVertex1( )
        { 
            return verts1;
        } 
        public VertexPositionColor[] getVertex2()
        {
            return verts2;
        }
        public VertexPositionColor[] getVertex3()
        {
            return verts3;
        }
    }
}
```

the strange thing is, verts1, vertes2,verts3 always get nulled after it exit the function.
so the getters method i have called after executing that always return null.

what should i do guys?

this is my call for the getters

```
math.calculate(v1, v2);
verts1 = math.getVertex1();
verts2 = math.getVertex2();
verts3 = math.getVertex3();
```

Comment: Do you call the getter on the same instance that you called calculate?

Comment: yes i do. i ll post my call under this post.

do you know how to not let the compiler delete the object? like protectThisVariable(verts1); ???

Comment: @r4ccoon if your objects are stored in member variables, all other things being equal they should not be losing their values.

Comment: yeah i know. that is why it is weird. hehe..
maybe if i am able to protect that variabel from deletion i can live peacefully now.

Comment: FYI. i have used the breakpoints.
after i click the "calculate" button, the value is there, the function did set the variable. 

but after it leaves the function, its contents are gone.

Comment: Could you please show us where and how the vert variables are declared; importantly: are they member variables within the class; and are they declared as private or public? That may help us diagnose the problem.

Comment: call getVertex1() in calculate right after you set verts1 and see if it's null.  The name reuse of verts1 is the only redflag I see.  How is verts1 declared (a property, a field).

Comment: do you mean?

math.calculate(v1, v2);
                verts1 = math.getVertex1();
                math.calculate(v1, v2);
                verts2 = math.getVertex2();
                math.calculate(v1, v2);
                verts3 = math.getVertex3();

Comment: No, inside calculate, right after you assign verts1. What does getVertex1() return?

Comment: i called the calculate 3 times. lol.

when i call calculate, the member variable in that class is set into the correct value. but it just gone after it leaves the function

Comment: it returns VertexPositionColor array. 
let me try to call getters on its own class.

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with it, so before I go completely insane, I'm mildly curious to see whether everything is broken, or just this one thing :-) Could you possibly try creating an extra member variable of type int, and then add a getter for it. Then, set the value of the integer in the calculate method. Then we'll see if it's just arrays that are broken here, or whether other, simpler data types are also broken.

Comment: Could I also ask how you're finding that the value is null? Are you just using a debugger with breakpoints, or are you *also* seeing the program crash due to it being null?

Comment: With the code as posted, it looks like it should work. Can you confirm that this is *exactly* the code that is playing up?

Comment: its remind me my problems with multi threading, are you checking the results right after this code?

Comment: Can you add some simple logging e.g.System.Console.Writeline(verts1.ToString()); after your code and debug - you may just be witnessing the gc cleaning up because you are not using the variables again - have you seen the bug with a real use case in place?

Comment: @Smashery, i have put some logic like -if this value is null dont do anything- so the program isnt crashing.

@marc gravell. i have state manager pattern in this program. that might be the one that acting up.

i am going to zip all the source code to let all of you download and analyze it. hehe..

Comment: FYI, the first time the program started, the value is set and not nulled after "calculate" execution. and then when i change state(home_state)(click back button in the program), and then go back to this state again(vector_state) it just nulled the variable after "calculate" being called.

Comment: here is the link to my project

http://www.mediafire.com/?sharekey=ff6f03bd91e7612bab1eab3e9fa335ca0b62c612f301a16b

Comment: i applied state manager pattern on the project.
see gameengine.cs and gamestate.cs

i have put some debugging log interface. double click anywhere on the window to open the log.

the vector_state has form_ui_vector object, and form_ui_vector that actually has math_vector class which is the problem in right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after fiddling the codes for 3 days, i now know what the problem are.
if you downloaded my code, and havent noticed it,

apparently the program were confused which textbox do they need to calculate, and which button that trigger what. that were caused by controls in a List<>

in the form_ui there are some method to add some controls into the list<>. 
i have put the code that removes the content of the list from the container. but it still not deleting the inside. !!!!!!!!!!!!!!! XDXP

so i have to put clear() in the List. then everything inside are gone.

now that problem are gone.

Answer (score 1):

If I had to guess I'm pretty sure you are using structs instead of classes. And most likely you just treat the struct instances as you would do with classes forgetting that they are copy-by-value. So you likely get an uninitialized one at some place (What you are seeing as "NULL").

Comment: +1, sounds like the most reasonable conclusion anyone here is going to come up with until you can share more of the code.

Comment: nope. it is a class. and none of them are struct. 
i had the problem before with the struct, but i have changed them to class.

Comment: here is the link to my project.

http://www.mediafire.com/?sharekey=ff6f03bd91e7612bab1eab3e9fa335ca0b62c612f301a16b